# What is the htaccess rule to do this?

Tags: .htaccess

What would be the htaccess rule to achieve the following please ?

I have a bunch of deleted URLs which i would like to simply 301 redirect to the homepage.

The URLS have this format, showthread.php?tid=405

Any parameter additional can also be redirected to the homepage.

eg. showthread.php?tid=405&pid=112

I would like to redirect by range, to save myself making individual entries, eg tid=405-420

They must all be redirected to the homepage (example.com) and my site is running in https.

I know i need to do something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/showthread\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule  https://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

but short of stuying htaccess rules for hours, i just can't figure it out. I'd appreciate some help. Thanks